# How can I create a list with data from Cloud FireStore using Future Builder

Tags: listview, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a Flutter application with a List View which retrieves data from Cloud Firestore. I'm running into issues with the Future Builder. Find my code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:awesome_loader/awesome_loader.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(OfferPage());

class OfferPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_OfferPageState createState() => _OfferPageState();
}

class _OfferPageState extends State<OfferPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.green[900]),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Click a Deal'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
      ),
      body: OfferScroll(),
    ));
    }
     }

    class OfferScroll extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _OfferScrollState createState() => _OfferScrollState();
     }

    class _OfferScrollState extends State<OfferScroll> {

     Future getOffers() async {
     var firestore = Firestore.instance;
     QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("Offers").getDocuments();
     return qn.documents;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getOffers(),
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                 child: AwesomeLoader(
                 loaderType: AwesomeLoader.AwesomeLoader3,
                 color: Colors.green[900],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["title"]));
              });
        }
      }),
);
}
}
```

I run into this error:

> The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#ea2bc):
>   A build function returned null.
>
> The offending widget is: FutureBuilder
>   Build functions must never return null.
>
> To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a return before the ListView.builder, otherwise the else branch will return null:

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["title"]));
    },
);
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcelGeirhos, Just forgot to add that. New to programming

Comment: Not the right solution for your problem? When it is the right solution please accept the answer. :)

Comment: Could you please check my other post, I need it working : https://stackoverflow.com/q/62208497/10616816

Comment: I think you should look for NetworkImage to load a image and then you can refer to the image url you would like to show.

Comment: Thank you, but how to use FireStore to retrieve that URL?

Comment: When you have the URL as a string in your FireStore i think you can retrieve the URL with someone like this: snapshot.data[index].data['imageFieldName'] and then you can give the return of this (the URL) to a NetworkImage to display the image.

Comment: Thank You! you can post this answer in the original thread where I can mark it as a answer.